# Set Active Directory user properties using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to set manager, department and title property of a user in active directory using C#.

Below is my code.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DomainName", "UserName", "Password"))
{
   using (var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context))
   {
     userPrincipal.SamAccountName = "UserSamACcountName";
       using (PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal))
       {
         UserPrincipal result = (UserPrincipal)search.FindOne();

         DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

         directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value = "<Manager Name>";
         directoryEntry.Properties["title"].Value = "<Designation>";
         directoryEntry.Properties["department"].Value = "<Department>";

         directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting below error when committing the changes.

> A constraint violation occurred.

After debugging I found out that these properties (manager,title,department) are not available in DirectoryEntry properties collection. I could set "mailNickName" property without any error.

Does anyone has any solution?

Comment: I googled it but not able to get the solution. From what I read, this error can occurred if data is not valid or malformed. I'm just passing all the parameters as string. nothing fancy I want. What exactly could be the issue.?

Comment: Now I'm getting the error that "The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid."

Comment: I know this is pseudo-anonymized but you are aware that `manager` should be a DN, not `"Manager Name"`, right?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Thanks for reminding me about Manager name being a DN. Issue is solved now.

Comment: so why don't you put the final solution? it would be great

Answer (score 0):

Your code is technically correct, but you are sending an illigal value for the `manager`property.

The `manager` property is a distinguished name, not just the name of the person

```
    directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value = "John Doe";
```

Will throw

> A constraint violation occurred.

Change your code to something like:

```
    directoryEntry.Properties["manager"].Value = "uid=john.doe,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com";
```